# Sending text and binary using sockets in python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, python-3.x

Hi i want send via socket xml like this.

```
<root>
  <image ID='2'>
    <![CDATA[ binary data with image ]]>
  </image>
</root>
```

I have problem because image is binary data and other part is string. I am sending multiple images and i need to have ID.

The main problem is what to do with binary data and string data. I tried to convert image to str but i cant revert this.

Comment: You can't just, say, base64-encode it, then base64-decode on the other end?

Comment: I never used base64-encode and i dont knew how to use it.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: I have everything expect sending image but now i will finish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A useful way to embed binary in `xml` is base64-encoding it. This is the approach `XAML` uses to send small images for example. You may do like this somewhere in your code:

```
import base64
img = open('some.png',rb').read()
base64.b64encode(img)

# append it to your buffer
```

And on the other side:

```
#get the img portion in the buffer
import base64
img = base64.b64decode(fetched_img)
# write it to disk or whatever
```

This is the *standard/usual* way to treat binary files inside `XML`.

Using `base64` is very simple, this is a example in the interpreter:

```
In [1]: import base64
In [4]: base64.b64encode('example')
Out[4]: 'ZXhhbXBsZQ=='
In [5]: base64.b64decode('ZXhhbXBsZQ==')
Out[5]: 'example'
```

You can read [the docs here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Inside `CDATA[ ... ]` there should be only the b64encoded file so this line: `stringResult =  base64.b64decode(stringResult) + base64.b64encode(f.read())` should be like this I guess: `stringResult = base64.b64encode(f.read())`. I don't see where you decode it though. Somewhere in the receiver, should be: `img_str=CDATA` (pseudocode here), `img = base64.b64decode(img_str)` to get the binaries into `img`

Comment: I have problem because if i want encoded image to string. It is conversion error. If i cast to strin base64 it is parsing but i dont knew how to revert str

Comment: Wow, I don't understand you quite well. The order is this: you `b64encode` something and it returns a string. Then you `b64decode` it and get what you first encoded back.

Comment: Yeah this is order byt b64encode returns bytes not string. Thats why i have problem.

Comment: I was able to encode, contatenate and later decode with a binary `.pdf` file. I don't know what your problem might be. You maybe want to open a new different question about your new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just connect the socket as binary - it is anyway and you probably don't care about newline conversion anyway.